# How can I install .exe files of Windows 7 or more in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, wine, winetricks

I want to run/install `.exe` files that require Windows 7 or higher in Wine on Ubuntu.

When I try to install a specific `.exe` file on Wine, it says

> Windows version is not supported! You can install it in Windows 7 or higher.

How can I configure which Windows version (XP, Vista, 7, 8, ...) Wine emulates?

Comment: Generally, .exes are for Windows, and Windows only. You can install some of them in wine, but not all.

Answer (score 16):

You can set the Windows version that Wine uses using `winecfg` or `winetricks`. After setting the `WINEPREFIX`, etc. (if you don't know what that is, you don't need to), run `winecfg`:

[image]

Select *Windows 7* from the *Windows Version* drop-down menu and click *OK*. That's it.

With `winetricks`, run:

```
winetricks win7
```